# Gnome-terminal doesn't close at end of SSH session

Tags: ssh, gnome-terminal

I have defined in gnome-terminal that it closes at end of shell. When I press Control-D or I execute exit, the terminal closes.

But if I open the SSH session with `gnome-terminal -x ssh server` and I execute `reboot` in the SSH session (*to reboot the remote server*), it hangs and it doesn't close. What's happening?

This worked to me before but I have to reinstall my Ubuntu (in local) and now gnome-terminal doesn't close itself when SSH session ends.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your remote server's `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile`, whichever is appropriate:

`alias reboot='{ sleep 2; reboot; }& exit'`

Every time you type 'reboot' on the remote server, it tells the computer to reboot in 2 seconds, while immediately exiting, ensuring your terminal won't just hang.

Edit:  have I misunderstood your question?

To close your terminal, after a SSH session ends, use an alias for sshing your server, and append 'exit' to the end:

`alias server_ssh='ssh user@site.com; exit'`

Put that in your ~/.bashrc

Answer (score 0):

The ssh server dies without properly closing the connection. The client will sit there because it doesn't know anything has happened to the server. The server has just remained quiet for a while; this is indistinguishable from the server being there but having nothing to say. Eventually the client will send a test packet, receive no reply, and die. You can hasten that by pressing a key; the client will send a real packet, receive no reply, and die. Or you can forcibly close the connection on the client by pressing <kbd>Return</kbd> then `~.`.

Comment: Is the problem in SSH server?

Comment: Think about it, if the server goes offline, how can it properly close the session?

Comment: When I reboot the server, it closes all services, included ssh server. In that moment, gnome-terminal should close itself. This worked before I reinstall my system (in local).

Comment: @Simón Everything is working as designed. `reboot` does the minimum to reboot as soon as possible while not leaving the system in an inconsistent state. This doesn't include giving user applications such as running SSH session a grace time to close gracefully.

Comment: It doesn't satisfy your responses. If this worked to me before, it should work now too. The problem must be in some misconfiguration or in a bug.

Comment: @Simón, what do you mean, "gnome-terminal should close itself"?  Do you mean your terminal window closes?  Does your terminal hang when  you type reboot in SSH? If it doesn't hang, then you can close gnome-terminal after SSHing easily using an alias.  `alias server_ssh='ssh user@server.com; exit'`  append to your ~/.bashrc or ~/.profile

Comment: I forgot to say that I open the SSH session with `gnome-terminal -x ssh server`.